# RequireJS - is jQuery case sensitive?

Tags: requirejs

I am attempting to get started with RequireJS, and am running into an annoying issue. . .

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'app_content/scripts',
    paths: {
        // the left side is the module ID,
        // the right side is the path to
        // the jQuery file, relative to baseUrl.
        // Also, the path should NOT include
        // the '.js' file extension. This example
        // is using jQuery 1.9.0 located at
        // js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js, relative to
        // the HTML page.
        'jQuery': 'lib/jQuery/jQuery-2.0.3'
    }
});
```

This, using uppercase `Q`, does not work, But if I change it to `jquery`, it does. Also, this is true in my required areas...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jQuery"], function ($) {
        console.log($);
    });
</script>
```

This returns `undefined`, but if I change everything to straight up `jquery`, it works.

Is this expected behavior, and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jQuery defines itself as 'jquery', all lowercase. That's normal.

If you open the source to jQuery you'll find:

```
// Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
// files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
// understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
// way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
// derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
// file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
// to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
}
```

So you have to refer to it as `"jquery"` everywhere in RequireJS calls. The issue here is that the `define` that jQuery uses is a ["named `define`"](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) which is something we normally do not use when creating modules. The RequireJS optimizer adds these names for us when we run it.

At any rate, when a "named `define`" is used the module name is set to the name given to `define` rather than by file names (as is otherwise the case when we don't use a named `define`).

It is possible to rename `"jquery"` to `"jQuery"`, like this:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "./js",
  paths: {
      "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2"
  }
});

define("jQuery", ["jquery"], function ($) {
   return $;
});

require(["jQuery"], function ($) {
   console.log($);
   console.log($("body")[0]);
});
```

I'm making use of the version of `define` that takes a name as the first parameter. Full example [here](https://github.com/lddubeau/requirejs-rename-jquery).

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't cover what the given RequireJS config changes *appear* to make it work.

Comment: Put another way: What is preventing an *alternate* module ID ('jQuery') from being used?

Comment: I've removed my downvote, but I'm still curious as to why an alias is not being added, even with a named define. I did find [this bit on anonymous modules](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Updating-existing-libraries#register-as-an-anonymous-module-) but it answers an orthogonal question.

Comment: ``paths`` is not the place to give new names to modules that are already named. I've updated my answer with a way to do it. It would also be possible to use a shim with an empty module to get the same result but this would require an empty file on disk (and an extra network request).

Comment: Fair enough. I'd still like to find where the behavior of "suppressing" alternative module IDs is documented, though :(

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely informative and helpful. At the end of the day, the "uppercase" 'Q' isn't a PROBLEM. It is less about jQuery specifically and more about understanding. I mean, I have my own conventions and behaviors, and that is the way I type, but this isn't a breaking one. But understanding the scope of what can cause these conflicts is very much something I deem important.

Comment: Instead of making a new `define`, in your require config you can just use a [star map](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map): `map: { '*': { "jQuery": "jquery" } }`.

Comment: @Brandon, regarding ``map`` the docs say: "This feature only works well for scripts that are real AMD modules that call define() and register as **anonymous modules**." (Emphasis mine.) jQuery does not register as an anonymous module.