# Why 'jquery' must be lowercase in RequireJS?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to use jQuery with RequireJS

**RequireConfig.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'lib/jquery'
    }
});
```

**Main.js**

```
define(['jQuery'], function($){
     // $ is undefined
});
```

The $ in the **Main.js** is undefined. But when I change **'jQuery'** to **'jquery'**, $ is correct.

RequireJS has special rule for the names in **paths**?

Why?

Comment: It's because jQuery defines itself as lowercase. Look at [this][1] answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552722/3485575

Comment: Many thanks for the link.