# requirejs can't see jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I have a simpliest project using requirejs. A data-main file is **js/default.js**

[image]

You can see there two jQuery files. RequireJS can see only that which is located on the same level that **default.js** So this code:

```
require(
    ['jquery', 'modules/module1', 'modules/module2'],
    function($, Module1, Module2){
        $('body')
            .append(Module1.phrase)
            .append('<hr/>')
            .append(Module2.ask);
    }
);
```

...works

But if I change **['jquery',  ...**  to **['libs/jquery',  ...** , it reveals an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

What's wrong here?
Whole code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QuFsKN597RD873MOlUw8?p=preview

Comment: You should probably see this: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery must indeed be required as [`jquery`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552722/1906307).

Now, there may be still confusion regarding the module name. Someone may look at the dependency `libs/jquery` and infer that jQuery *is* in fact required as `jquery`. That is, doing `require(['libs/jquery'], ...` would be asking RequireJS to load the module `jquery` located in `libs/`. However, *this is not the case*. The module name of the module being required is the *entire name* listed in the dependency list. So in the `require` call above, the module name of the module required is `libs/jquery`. But jQuery calls `define('jquery', ...` to declare itself to RequireJS. The module name (the first argument is `jquery`, not `libs/jquery` and thus RequireJS fails to find the module requested.

A trivial fix is to add a `paths` configuration:

```
paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the requirejs docs:

> jQuery defines named AMD module 'jquery' (all lower case) when it detects AMD/RequireJS. To reduce confusion, we recommend using 'jquery' as the module name in your requirejs.config.

http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html