# requireJS Object prototype may only be an Object or null - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, requirejs

I am experiencing problems with requireJS. I am trying to load jQuery along with my other scripts, but I get an error. Here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="./app" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.min.js">  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    require.config({
        paths: {
            jQuery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min',
            helpers: 'helpers',
        },
        shim: {
            jQuery: {
                exports: '$'
            }
        }
    });

    requirejs(['main']);
})();
```

**main.js**

```
define(function(require){
    require(['jQuery', 'helpers'], function($){
        $('body').css({'background': 'red'});
    });
});
```

**helpers.js**

```
define(function(){
    'use strict';

    Object.prototype.extend = function(parentClass){
        if(!Object.create){
            Object.prototype.create = function(proto){
                function F(){}
                F.prototype = proto;
                return new F();
            };
        }
        this.prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype);
        this.prototype.constructor = this;
    }
});
```

I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`
at line 12 of *helpers.js* It looks like once jQuery is required it fires all of the Object.prototype properties. Because:

```
define(function(){
    'use strict';

    Object.prototype.extend = function(parentClass){
        alert('This code shoud be executed only when called on objects!');
        if(!Object.create){
            Object.prototype.create = function(proto){
                function F(){}
                F.prototype = proto;
                return new F();
            };
        }
        this.prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype);    //The error occurs here because the code in the scope is executed and parentClass is undefined
        this.prototype.constructor = this;
    }
});
```

Alerts the message in the extend method. Why? jQuery works fine with my script if requireJS is not being used. Any help?

File structure:

testAppFolder

- index.html
- app.js
- helpers.js
- main.js

Comment: Can you see in the callstack where `extend` is being called? Is it getting called without an argument somewhere?

Comment: `extend` is not being called anywhere. You can create the same files as in the example and you will face the same problem without calling the `extend` method. I've tried with `Object.prototype.asdfh` and the method is called again. All of the `Object.prototype.METHOD_NAME` are being called automatically on initialization.

Comment: You are saying both that it is _not being called_ and that it is _being called automatically_. Which is it?

Comment: @Mathletics I say that nowhere in my app I am not calling the `extend` method. On the initialization itself, it's being called automatically, that's the actual problem.

Comment: @Mathletics I mean I am not calling the `extend` function. I wrote it in case I need to extend my classes in the future. jQuery somehow calls it itself immediately the line `require(['jQuery', 'helpers'], function($){..}` is reached. if I use just `require(['helpers'], function(){..}` then the `extend` method is not fired since it's not called anywhere yet. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't mess with `Object.prototype`. The problem you ran into is just *one* of many possible problems it may cause. **The proper solution to your problem is to use another approach than adding `extend` to `Object.prototype`.**

Why does it not work? When you do `Object.prototype.extend = function () {...` you are declaring a new property on `Object.prototype` and by default this property is *enumerable*. What this means is that when after this assignment has taken effect if you do `for (var i in {}) console.log(i);` you'll get `extend` on the console.

Now, jQuery has a nice function named [`extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). The funny thing is that when jQuery initializes, it uses `jQuery.extend` to extend itself. If you look at the jQuery source, you'll see things like:

```
jQuery.extend( {
    expando: ...,
    isReady: ...,
});
```

When `extend` is called with only one argument, it means the thing to be expanded is `this`, which is `jQuery` itself. So `extend` takes the object it was passed as argument and iterates through its properties with a `for...in` loop. Which is all nice an well until it runs into the `extend` that you've added to `Object.prototype`. When it gets to this property, it overwrites its own `extend` method with the one from `Object.prototype`. So the *next time* `jQuery.extend` is run, it runs the code you've assigned to `Object.prototype.extend` and you get the error you get.

You should also refer to the jQuery module as `jquery` not `jQuery`, and remove the `shim` configuration for it. jQuery calls `define` (therefore no `shim` for it) and it hardcodes its name as `jquery`. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552722/1906307) for further details.

---

**The following is for illustration purposes only. Do not use in production code.**

If you replace your `helpers.js` with the following code, then the problem will go away:

```
define(function() {
  'use strict';

  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "extend", {
    value: function(parentClass) {
      if (!Object.create) {
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "create", {
          value: function(proto) {
            function F() {}
            F.prototype = proto;
            return new F();
          },
          enumerable: false,
          writable: true
        });
      }
      this.prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype);
      this.prototype.constructor = this;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true
  });

});
```

This uses [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define `extend` as a non-enumerable property so it won't show in `for...in`. It is also writable, which allows jQuery to define its own `jQuery.extend`. It does the same for `create`.

Comment: Glad to help. I've edited my answer to add a note regarding the name of the jQuery module and the fact that the shim is unnecessary. I suggest looking at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35616986/revisions) to see the change I made to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the fact that it's not a good practice to attach methods directly to objects. Therefore I've created my own library like:

```
define(function(){

    var _ = (function(){
        'use strict';

        function _(o){
            if(!(this instanceof _)){
                return new _(o);
            }
            this.o = o;
        }

        _.isArray = function(arg){
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
        };

        _.prototype = {

            extend: function(parentClass){
                if(!Object.create){
                    Object.prototype.create = function(proto){
                        function F(){}
                        F.prototype = proto;
                        return new F();
                    }
                }
                this.o.prototype = Object.create(parentClass.prototype);
                this.o.prototype.constructor = this;
            }

            // Other methods here

        };

        return _;
    })();

    return _;
});
```

And use like that:

```
var MyClass = (function(){ ... })();
var MyOtherClass = (function(){
    _(MyOtherClass).extend(MyClass);

    function MyOtherClass(){
        //constructor
    }

    return MyOtherClass;
})();
```

And no more errors :)