# requireJs first steps - $ undefined

Tags: requirejs

try to get familiar with require JS - but I don't understand what is wrong with this setup - can't call the $(document).foundation() because $ is undefined.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
        jQuery:         'script.php?file=jquery.min.js',
        foundation:     'script.php?file=foundation.min.js'
    }
});

require(['jQuery'], function($) {
    require(['foundation'], function() {
        $(document).foundation(); // $ undefined?
    });

    // ... more code with different require sections
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequireJS - is jQuery case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552662/requirejs-is-jquery-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving your logic into a separate file, for example `app.js`

Then, change the `require(['jQuery'], function($) { ...` call to something like `requirejs(['app'])`.

In `app.js` you should define a module, something like:

```
define(['jQuery', 'foundation'], function($, foundation) {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Comment: would it also work if I just write:

    `define(['jQuery', 'foundation'], function($) {
        $(document).foundation();
    });`

because I do not need the foundation var - or must it be write like your way?

Comment: Theoretically yes, give it a try

Comment: gilad - may I ask you a further question to better understand:

are both versions working:

    `// version 1
    define(['jQuery', 'foundation'], function($, foundation) {
        $(document).foundation();
    });

    define(['jQuery', 'fancybox'], function($, fancybox) {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });

    // version 2
    define(['jQuery'], function($) {
     define(['foundation'], function($) {
         $(document).foundation();
     });
 
     define(['fancybox'], function($) {
         $(".fancybox").fancybox();
     });
    });`

Comment: Just try around. Choose the option that works (or the syntax you like better if they both work).