# jQuery dependency error with Require js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am facing loading of JQuery dependency scripts with Require Js

I am having Jquery Plugins, jQuery Library and 2 module js

assets > js > vendor > jQuery Library,
assets > js > apps.js, pageTop.js, categoryJS.js

My apps.js:

```
require.config({
    'baseUrl':'assets/js',

    'paths':{

       'jQuery':'vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min',
       'viewportSize':'viewportSize-min',
       'isoTopFilter':'isotope.pkgd.min',
       'categoryJS'  :'categoryJS'

    },

    shim:{

         'jQuery': {
            'exports':'$'
         },

         'viewportSize' :{
            deps:['jQuery']
         },

         'isoTopFilter':{
            deps:['jQuery']
         },

         'pageTop':{
            deps:['jQuery']
         },

         'categoryJS':{
            deps:['jQuery']
         }
    }
});//require.config

define(['jQuery','viewportSize','isoTopFilter','pageTop','categoryJS'], function($, pageTop, categoryJS) {

$(function() {
pageTop.alertProduct();
categoryJS.categorySlider();
});
});
```

and my pageTop.js

```
define([],function( ){
    return {

  alertProduct: function(){
    alert('I am module2');
    return true;
  }

  }

});
```

My categoryJs.js

```
define([],function( ){
  return {

  categorySlider: function(){
    alert('I am module2');
    return true;
  }

  }

});
```

The script is not loading, getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertProduct' of undefined
```

Can some one please help me, I have tried by all means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
define(['jQuery','viewportSize','isoTopFilter','pageTop','categoryJS'],
       function($, pageTop, categoryJS)
```

Look at the list of dependencies and the list of arguments. `pageTop` is the 2nd argument so it will get the value of the `viewportSize` module. There's no magic here: each module listed in the dependencies *is* passed to the callback and it is passed in the same order as it appears in the dependencies. Assuming you do not need the values of `viewportSize` and `isoTopFilter` you could do this:

```
define(['jquery','pageTop','categoryJS','viewportSize','isoTopFilter'],
       function($, pageTop, categoryJS)
```

Also,

- jQuery calls `define` so you cannot set a `shim` for it. (It most likely will be ignored.) You should remove the `shim` you set for it.

  Same with your own modules. If you call `define` and want to set a list of dependencies, pass the dependencies to `define`, do not set `shim` for these modules. `shim` is only for code that does not call `define`.
- jQuery hardcodes its module name as `jquery` so you have to refer to it as `jquery` all lowercase. (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552722/1906307).) Change your `paths` so that you have `jquery` there instead of `jQuery`.