# Problems using jQuery with requirejs

Tags: jquery, requirejs, amd

I can't get jQuery to work with requirejs.

I have the following code in main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
    'jQuery': '../bower_components/jQuery/dist/jquery.min'
      }
    });

require(['jQuery'], function(jq) {

   console.log(jq); // gives undefined

   jq( document.body ).click(function() { // Gives Uncaught TypeError: jq is not a function
    console.log("jqueryworks");
    });


 });
```

jq is returned as undefined and jq(document.body) gives jq is not a function.

Can anyone point out what is wrong and how it should be configured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequireJS - is jQuery case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552662/requirejs-is-jquery-case-sensitive)

Comment: Your problem is the same as in the other question: you cannot require the `jquery` module as `jQuery` because they've hardcoded the module name in the code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. That fixed it.

Comment: Glad to help. The system should be prompting you as to whether the duplicate answers your question. Please click in the affirmative.